# Client types in OAuth2 Spec

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm having trouble understanding a phrase in the latest version of the OAuth2 spec (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23 at the time of this writing). I came across this paragraph in [section 2.1 about client types](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-2.1):

```
The authorization server SHOULD NOT make assumptions about the client
type, nor accept the type information provided by the client
developer without first establishing trust.
```

What exactly does "establishing trust" mean in this context? According to the spec, the client type is a piece of information that the client must provide at registration time that later affects the authorization flow, and it is either "confidential" or "public."

Comment: In new version (draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27 at the moment) the second half sentence has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret

> The authorization server SHOULD NOT make assumptions about the client
>   type, nor accept the type information provided by the client
>   developer without first establishing trust.

To mean that it is recommended that the client be registered to the server and has authenticated itself to the server before the server acts upon any requests.  If your server differentiates in response between public and confidential clients, it should not trust the client's assurance that it is confidential(or otherwise) until it is authenticated to the server.